# Haskell STM not giving output or deriving Show not giving any output

Tags: haskell

I am writing a telnet console in haskell with this code

```hs
module Main (main) where

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

import Control.Concurrent (forkFinally)
import qualified Control.Exception as E
import Control.Monad (unless, forever, void)
import Control.Monad.STM (STM, atomically)
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TVar (TVar, newTVar, writeTVar, readTVar)

import qualified Data.ByteString as S
import Network.Socket (close, setSocketOption)
import Network.Socket (HostName)
import Network.Socket (ServiceName, AddrInfo)
import Network.Socket (Socket, SocketType(Stream))
import Network.Socket (addrFlags, getAddrInfo, gracefulClose, accept, listen, addrAddress, bind, setCloseOnExecIfNeeded, openSocket, withFdSocket, SocketOption(ReuseAddr))
import Network.Socket (addrSocketType, defaultHints, AddrInfoFlag(AI_PASSIVE))
import Network.Socket.ByteString (recv, sendAll)

data Störm = An | Aus deriving Show

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = runTCPServer Nothing "3000" (talk $ newTVar Aus)
  where
    talk :: STM (TVar Störm) -> Socket -> IO ()
    talk state' s = recv s 1024 >>= \msg -> unless (S.null msg) $
      case C.unpack msg of
        "exit\r\n" -> sendAll s (C.pack "Auf Widerhoren")
        "an\r\n" -> sendAll s (C.pack "Am An\n") >> putStrLn "Am An" >> write state' An >> talk state' s
        "aus\r\n" -> sendAll s (C.pack "Am Aus\n") >> putStrLn "Am Aus" >> write state' Aus >> talk state' s
        "anzeigen\r\n" -> sendAll s <$> (atomically $ C.pack <$> show <$> (state' >>= readTVar)) >> putStrLn "Am Anzeigen State" >> talk state' s
        otherwise -> sendAll s (C.pack "Unbekannte Befehl\n") >> putStrLn (show msg) >> (talk (state') s)
    write :: STM (TVar Störm) -> Störm -> IO ()
    write state new = atomically $ state >>= \s -> writeTVar s new

runTCPServer :: Maybe HostName -> ServiceName -> (Socket -> IO a) -> IO a
runTCPServer mhost port server = resolve >>= \addr -> (E.bracket (open addr) close loop)
  where
    resolve :: IO AddrInfo
    resolve = do
        let hints = defaultHints {
                addrFlags = [AI_PASSIVE]
              , addrSocketType = Stream
              }
        head <$> getAddrInfo (Just hints) mhost (Just port)

    open :: AddrInfo -> IO Socket
    open addr = E.bracketOnError (openSocket addr) close $ \sock -> do
        setSocketOption sock ReuseAddr 1
        withFdSocket sock setCloseOnExecIfNeeded
        bind sock $ addrAddress addr
        listen sock 1024
        return sock

    loop :: Socket -> IO b0
    loop sock = forever $ E.bracketOnError (accept sock) (close . fst)
        $ \(conn, _peer) -> void $
            -- 'forkFinally' alone is unlikely to fail thus leaking @conn@,
            -- but 'E.bracketOnError' above will be necessary if some
            -- non-atomic setups (e.g. spawning a subprocess to handle
            -- @conn@) before proper cleanup of @conn@ is your case
            forkFinally (server conn) (const $ gracefulClose conn 5000)
```

which uses the packages

```
base ^>=4.16.4.0
                    , network ^>=3.1.4.0
                    , bytestring
                    , stm
```

When connect to the telnet to the console from a telnet session, and run `an` or `aus` and then `anzeigen` or just directly the console not returns the corresponding `An` or `Aus` message to the telnet client but only an space, meanwhile I know that the case is being properly selected because the message `Am Anzeigen State` is being showed in the server's stdout.

I have not idea why this is happening.

Comment: As a general debugging tip, there's _way_ too much happening all at once in your function. Give proper names to intemediate results and type them, that'll make it way easier to spot small mistakes like this.

Comment: @Cubic I do it a lot, just that I also refactor it back to 'one liners' after the fact.

Comment: Well, you can do it however you want, but it'll be easier to work with (both for you and anyone else you show this to) if you don't insist on dense one-liners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not sending anything.

In your "anzeigen" handler, you have this code (renaming `partThatDoesntMatter = (atomically $ C.pack <$> show <$> (state' >>= readTVar))`

```
sendAll s <$> partThatDoesntMatter >> putStrLn "Am Anzeigen State"
```

This just an alternate spelling of

```
fmap (sendAll s) partThatDoesntMatter >> putStrLn "Am Anzeigen State"
```

You want to send something using `sendAll` here, but your `fmap` call here is just producing a `sendAll` action that never gets executed (and immediately discarded by the `>>` afterwards).

What you need here is

```
partThatDoesntMatter >>= sendAll s >> putStrLn "Am Anzeigen State"
```

Compare:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

applied to our example this is the difference between

```
sendAll s :: ByteString -> IO ()
partThatDoesntMatter :: IO ByteString
fmap (sendAll s) partThatDoesntMatter :: IO (IO ())
partThatDoesntMatter >>= sendAll s :: IO ()
```