# Possibly discarded by lazyness STM write operation

Tags: haskell

I am writing a telnet console in haskell with this code

```hs
module Main (main) where

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

import Control.Concurrent (forkFinally)
import qualified Control.Exception as E
import Control.Monad (unless, forever, void)
import Control.Monad.STM (STM, atomically)
import Control.Concurrent.STM.TVar (TVar, newTVar, writeTVar, readTVar)

import qualified Data.ByteString as S
import Network.Socket (close, setSocketOption)
import Network.Socket (HostName)
import Network.Socket (ServiceName, AddrInfo)
import Network.Socket (Socket, SocketType(Stream))
import Network.Socket (addrFlags, getAddrInfo, gracefulClose, accept, listen, addrAddress, bind, setCloseOnExecIfNeeded, openSocket, withFdSocket, SocketOption(ReuseAddr))
import Network.Socket (addrSocketType, defaultHints, AddrInfoFlag(AI_PASSIVE))
import Network.Socket.ByteString (recv, sendAll)

data Störm = An | Aus deriving Show

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = runTCPServer Nothing "3000" (talk $ newTVar Aus)
  where
    talk :: STM (TVar Störm) -> Socket -> IO ()
    talk state' s = recv s 1024 >>= \msg -> unless (S.null msg) $
      case C.unpack msg of
        "exit\r\n" -> sendAll s (C.pack "Auf Widerhoren")
        "an\r\n" -> sendAll s (C.pack "Am An\n") >> putStrLn "Am An" >> write state' An >> talk state' s
        "aus\r\n" -> sendAll s (C.pack "Am Aus\n") >> putStrLn "Am Aus" >> write state' Aus >> talk state' s
        "anzeigen\r\n" -> (atomically $ C.pack <$> show <$> (state' >>= readTVar)) >>= sendAll s >> putStrLn "Am Anzeigen State" >> talk state' s
        otherwise -> sendAll s (C.pack "Unbekannte Befehl\n") >> putStrLn (show msg) >> (talk (state') s)
    write :: STM (TVar Störm) -> Störm -> IO ()
    write state new = atomically $ state >>= \s -> writeTVar s new

runTCPServer :: Maybe HostName -> ServiceName -> (Socket -> IO a) -> IO a
runTCPServer mhost port server = resolve >>= \addr -> (E.bracket (open addr) close loop)
  where
    resolve :: IO AddrInfo
    resolve = do
        let hints = defaultHints {
                addrFlags = [AI_PASSIVE]
              , addrSocketType = Stream
              }
        head <$> getAddrInfo (Just hints) mhost (Just port)

    open :: AddrInfo -> IO Socket
    open addr = E.bracketOnError (openSocket addr) close $ \sock -> do
        setSocketOption sock ReuseAddr 1
        withFdSocket sock setCloseOnExecIfNeeded
        bind sock $ addrAddress addr
        listen sock 1024
        return sock

    loop :: Socket -> IO b0
    loop sock = forever $ E.bracketOnError (accept sock) (close . fst)
        $ \(conn, _peer) -> void $
            -- 'forkFinally' alone is unlikely to fail thus leaking @conn@,
            -- but 'E.bracketOnError' above will be necessary if some
            -- non-atomic setups (e.g. spawning a subprocess to handle
            -- @conn@) before proper cleanup of @conn@ is your case
            forkFinally (server conn) (const $ gracefulClose conn 5000)
```

which uses the packages

```
base ^>=4.16.4.0
                    , network ^>=3.1.4.0
                    , bytestring
                    , stm
```

When connect to the telnet to the console from a telnet session, and run `an` or `aus` and then `anzeigen` I always get the default value `Aus`. When it should be rewritten by the value `An` or `Aus` depending of the entry given.

By the anterior problem [Haskell STM not giving output or deriving Show not giving any output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76875403/haskell-stm-not-giving-output-or-deriving-show-not-giving-any-output?noredirect=1#comment135524682_76875403) I think probably is something similar, but no sure how to solve, already tried to change the `write state' Aus >>` to `write state' >>` to `write state' >>= \_ ->` but I did not work and make a lot of sense that it never worked, but have not idea of how to solve it.

Comment: Replacing `>>` with `>>= \_ ->` does nothing, they're equivalent for monads.

Comment: I only had a very quick look. My guess is that you have `STM (TVar ...) > ...` where you actually need `TVar .. -> ...`. Right now when you run `talk $ newTVar Aus` you are not passing to `talk` a single tvar, but an STM action that will create a fresh tvar each time! I guess, you don't want that. So, you need to pass only the  `TVar ..` around (not `STM (TVar ...)` ). Changing to the new type you will find several type errors you'll need to fix.

Comment: `talk` should just take a `TVar Störm` instead of `STM (TVar Störm)`. For that matter, there's really no reason for this to be a `TVar` instead of an IORef, or even just a plain old value here.

Comment: @Cubic `Störm` is only a place holder for a value that will be shared between the master thread and the connection threads.

Comment: @Cubic How it solved it?